# NoMethodError on collection_select input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have been trying different things to fix this and it's driving me nuts...

I have an input field:

```
<%= collection_select(:stakeholder, :user_id, User.all, :id, :first_name) %>
```

Each stakeholder has a user_id attribute, which is an integer.

When I try to render the form, I get this NoMethodError:

```
undefined method `id' for 2:Fixnum
```

Any ideas?

Edit: adding full form view

```
 <%= simple_form_for([@project, @stakeholder]) do |f| %>
 <%= f.error_notification %>

 <div class="form-inputs">
  <%= f.input :first_name %>
  <%= f.input :last_name %>
  <%= f.input :email %>
  <%= f.input :address %>
  <%= f.input :city %>
  <%= f.input :sentiment,  %>
  <%= f.label :tags, "Tags (separated by commas)" %>
  <%= collection_select(:stakeholder, :user_id, User.all, :id, :first_name) %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
</div>
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :account
has_many :stakeholders

def set_default_role
 self.role ||= :user
end

# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :invitable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

stakeholder.rb

```
class Stakeholder < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :project
has_many :notes
belongs_to :user
acts_as_taggable

def full_name
  full_name = "#{first_name.capitalize} #{last_name.capitalize}"
end

end
```

Comment: Post your view please. I can tell you right now, you're passing in an ID where your view is expecting to see an object (likely @user), but I can't say for sure without seeing your view.

Comment: I added the entire form view above. The /new view just renders the form partial.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select).

```
collection_select(object, method, collection, value_method,
text_method, options = {}, html_options = {}) public

Returns <select> and <option> tags for the collection of existing
return values of method for object's class. The value returned from
calling method on the instance object will be selected.
```

You seem to have an extra argument in your `collection_select` tag which is causing Rails to call `:id` as a method when it's actually a number (2).

user_id is a field in some Stakeholder object, right? So unless I'm misunderstanding how you've set up your relationships, stakeholder isn't relevant (in the sense that all you want is a user ID from your form).

This line should get you what you want.

```
<%= f.collection_select(:user_id, @users, :id, :first_name)
```

Comment: Thanks. This produces the same error. I also get the error with simple nav links like: 

     <li class="name"><%= link_to 'My account', account_path(current_user.account) %></li>

This is causing me to think that maybe my User model is screwed up in some way...

Comment: Post the model then (which is what I originally meant to ask for). Also, in your controller, humor me by adding the line (at)users = User.all and replacing User.all in your view with (at)users. Naturally, (at) should be replaced with the 'at sign' -- SO complains if I actually use the symbol in comments more than once.

Comment: Done. I tried it with @users instead of User.all. It now shows the error in the controller on the (at)users = User.all line. Same error.

Comment: Interesting. If you look at Schema.rb, do you have an ID column, or is it maybe misnamed 'user_id' or something like that?

Comment: There's no id in schema.rb, though I'm using devise (and I can see each user does have an id in rails console). Very strange...

Comment: Sorry. schema.rb shouldn't have an id column -- every table has that column, implicitly, so I'm sure it's there. Wasn't thinking.